# Direct limits of $\sigma$-centered forcing notions

Tags: set-theory, forcing, boolean-algebras

It is quite well known that

*Any FS (finite support) iteration of length $<\mathfrak{c}^+$ of $\sigma$-centered posets is $\sigma$-centered (see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84124/finite-support-iterations-of-sigma-centered-forcing-notions)).*

Now consider the following question: whenever $\delta<\mathfrak{c}^+$ is a limit ordinal of uncountable cofinality and $\langle\mathbb{P}_{\alpha}:\alpha<\delta\rangle$ is a sequence of $\sigma$-centered posets such that

(i) $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ is a complete subposet of $\mathbb{P}_\beta$ for all $\alpha<\beta<\delta$, and

(ii) $\mathbb{P}_\gamma=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ for any limit $\gamma<\delta$,

do we have that $\mathbb{P}_\delta:=\bigcup_{\alpha<\delta}\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ is $\sigma$-centered? Is this correct in the case $\delta=\omega_1$?

Note that this may not be a consequence of the result mentioned at the beginning since the quotient of two $\sigma$-centered posets is not necessarily (forced to be) $\sigma$-centered.

Any help with this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I feel like there is a counter-example arising from something like, the failure of uniformization for a ladder-system on $\omega_1$.  However a specific example escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Can you give an example of a composition  $P*Q$ which is $\sigma$-centered, where $P$ forces that $Q$ is not $\sigma$-centered?

Comment: @Goldstern The most natural (but in this case artificial) is, under $\text{MA}_{\aleph_1}$, $C*T$ where $C$ is Cohen forcing and $T$ is the Suslin tree it adds (recall that  $\text{MA}_{\aleph_1}$ implies that any poset of size $\aleph_1$ is $\sigma$-centered).
Now, assuming  $\text{MA}_{\aleph_1}$, perform a finite support iteration of length $\omega_2$ using $C*T$. I wonder whether the resulting poset is $\sigma$-centered

Comment: Can't you take a strongly proper forcing $P$ of size $\aleph_1$ that is not c.c.c, then consider some increasing internally approachable countable elementary submodels $\langle M_\alpha: \alpha<\omega_1\rangle$, then $\langle P\cap M_\alpha: \alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ seems to work.